# Real numbers intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that there always exists a irrational number in any open interval of real numbers? I guess yes, but I could not prove it. Could any help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In every open real interval, there are infinitely many irrational and also infinitely many rational numbers.

Comment: take any two numbers $a<b$ in the interval. If one is irrational, you are done. Otherwise, take $a+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(b-a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $p/q$ is a rational number in your open interval $(a,b)$. Then the sequence $$a_n=\dfrac{p}{q}+\dfrac{1}{n}\sqrt{2}$$ consists solely of irrational numbers and converges obviously to $\dfrac{p}{q}$ (as $n \to \infty$), so that in every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $B_\epsilon(p/q)$ (for $\epsilon>0$) there are infinitely many of the irrational $a_n$'s. Now, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $$B_\epsilon(p/q) \subset (a,b)$$ so that you have actually proven more, i.e. that there are infitely many irrational numbers in every open interval and in particular in every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of every rational number.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, (i.e., given any open set $U$ in $\Bbb R$, $U\cap \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\not=\emptyset$,) then it will be clear.